# SQL: Query to find multiple items with a common value in one field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a DB that is structured like this:

```
UserInfo
----------
Id (INT PK AI)
UserId (INT)
InfoTypeId (INT FK -> InfoType.Id)
Value (varchar)

InfoType
----------
Id (INT PK AI)
InfoTypeName (VARCHAR)
```

The rows represent information for a given user.  For instance, I may have the following rows in the `InfoType` table:

```
Id | InfoTypeName
-----------------
1  | "First Name"
2  | "Last Name"
3  | "Age"
```

and rows in `UserInfo` like this:

```
Id | UserId | InfoTypeId | Value
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1          | "John"
2  | 1      | 2          | "Smith"
3  | 1      | 3          | "20"
4  | 2      | 1          | "John"
5  | 2      | 2          | "Doe"
6  | 2      | 3          | "30"
7  | 3      | 1          | "Jane"
8  | 3      | 2          | "Doe"
9  | 3      | 3          | "25"
10 | 4      | 1          | "John"
11 | 4      | 2          | "Smith"
12 | 4      | 3          | "25"
```

I want to create a query that deletes all rows from the UserInfo table that refer to a user whose first name is "John" and last name is "Smith".  This means that I want to delete rows 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, and 12.  I can't figure out how to write the query.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get a list of userIDs with

```
SELECT DISTINCT ui1.UserId 
FROM UserInfo ui1
    INNER JOIN UserInfo ui2 
    ON ui1.UserId = ui2.UserId
WHERE (ui1.InfoTypeId = 1 AND ui1.Value = "John" AND ui2.InfoTypeId = 2 AND ui2.Value = "Smith");
```

And further, a list of rows to delete with

```
SELECT * FROM UserInfo ui WHERE ui.UserId IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ui1.UserId 
    FROM UserInfo ui1
        INNER JOIN UserInfo ui2 
        ON ui1.UserId = ui2.UserId
    WHERE (ui1.InfoTypeId = 1 AND ui1.Value = "John" AND ui2.InfoTypeId = 2 AND ui2.Value = "Smith"));
```

But when I replace the `SELECT` with a `DELETE` as such:

```
DELETE FROM UserInfo WHERE UserId IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ui1.UserId 
    FROM UserInfo ui1
        INNER JOIN UserInfo ui2 
        ON ui1.UserId = ui2.UserId
    WHERE (ui1.InfoTypeId = 1 AND ui1.Value = "John" AND ui2.InfoTypeId = 2 AND ui2.Value = "Smith"));
```

I get

```
SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'UserInfo' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` here:

```
delete ui
    from UserInfo ui join
         (select ui.UserId,
                 max(case when it.InfoTypeName = 'First name' then value end) as first_name,
                 max(case when it.InfoTypeName = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name
          from UserInfo ui join
               InfoType it
               on ui.InfoTypeId = it.id
          group by ui.UserId
         ) uu
         using (UserId)
    where uu.first_name = 'John' and uu.last_name = 'Smith';
```

Comment: I ran the subquery on its own `select ui.UserId,
 max(case when it.TypeName = 'First name' then value end) as first_name,
    max(case when it.TypeName = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name
from UserInfo ui 
 join InfoType it
    on ui.InfoTypeId = it.rowid
group by ui.UserId;` and it resulted null values for First Name and Last Name in all 4 rows

Comment: NOTE: I had to change a couple things because I realized I set up my test DB slightly differently.  I named the column "TypeName" instead of "InfoTypeName" and used sqlite so there's an implicit rowid

Comment: @ewok . . . You should ask a new question.  This question is tagged MySQL and this is the correct MySQL answer.  SQLite is quite different.

Comment: ok fair enough.  though one comment, you have a stray comma after `last_name`.  After spinning up a MySql and testing there. it works.

Comment: follow up, can this be extended to more than 2 fields?  I.e. what if I have a middle name field and I want to delete all "John David Smith"s?

Comment: @ewok . . . I think it can be extended.  If it is not obvious how to, then you can ask a new question.